# If a line starts with a certain character, remove the previous newline

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a series of lines from a story that have been wrapped:

```
Little Sue went
out to play, and
found herself a log.
The log was
heavy.
```

I would like to unwrap the text. If a line starts with a lowercase letter, then the previous newline should be removed, and replaced with a space, with this end result:

```
Little Sue went out to play, and found herself a log.
The log was heavy.
```

I've found some examples of sed doing pattern matching across newlines, but they're always for removing the newline *after* the pattern match. I've tried constructing some commands in sed, but it's not working quite right. They seem to act only on every other line. I think it's because sed is finishing with a pair of lines, printing them, then throwing them out before consuming the next lines.

```
sed 'N;/\n[a-z]/s/\n/ /;P;D' wrapped.txt
  Little Sue went out to play, and
  found herself a log.
  The log was heavy.
sed 'N;/\n[a-z]/s/\n\([a-z]\)/ \1/' wrapped.txt
  Little Sue went out to play, and
  found herself a log.
  The log was
  heavy.
```

I have GNU sed 4.2.2 on my Fedora 20 machine. Does anyone know whether sed is capable of what I want? Or, if sed won't do, then any program or language common on Linux boxes would be fine.

Comment: In your first sed solution you are very nearly there! However remember once the newline is removed the pattern space after printing will be deleted completely and hence the processing will begin again with the next line. In order to restore the pattern space to two lines you need to loop back to the beginning i.e. `:a;N;/\n[a-z]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D` thus preventing the commands from recycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily done through Perl,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/\n(?=[a-z])/ /g' file
Little Sue went out to play, and found herself a log.
The log was heavy.
```

Comment: This does indeed work, thanks. Also, later on I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208059/using-awk-or-sed-to-remove-newlines-based-on-first-character-of-next-line), and one of the answers helped me build this, which uses more basic (in my experiance) regex: `perl -0pe 's/\n([a-z])/ \1/g' file`